# Como cambiar 2 lineas de c++ a C

Tags: c++, c

Como puedo cambiar esto de c++ a c?
el cout cambiarlo por printf

```
void imprimeVector(const vector<string>& v)
     {

         for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)

          cout << v[i] << " ";

    }
```

Gracias!

Comment: Hola! Has intentado algo para resolver esta pregunta? Qué pasa cuando intentas compilar tu código en C? Además, tu código no es un [ejemplo mínimo verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), así que nadie podrá replicar el problema que sea que tengas :)

Comment: no se como cambiarlo por printf para que me compile en c no c++

Comment: te muestro mi codigo completo?

Comment: Siempre se muestra todo el código relevante. :) Estaba intentando que aprendieras a formular una buena pregunta (de las que se responden más rápido) pero parece que alguien ya te dio la respuesta.

Comment: No es solo `cout`, esa función recibe un `std:vector`, clase que no está disponible en C... tienes alguna estructura de C que reemplace a este objeto?

Comment: @eferion en vez de vector sería un char* [] no?

Comment: @RuslanLopez por ejemplo

Answer (score 2):

Te pongo un ejemplo con un entero:

```
int entero = 5;
printf("El valor es %d.\n", contador);
```

Segun el tipo de la variable tienes que poner un % determinado:

%s : Strings

%f : float

etc.

Aqui hay más información: http://www.it.uc3m.es/pbasanta/asng/course_notes/input_output_printf_es.html

Comment: Los `template` no existen en [tag:c] ¿Qué hace con `vector<string>`?

Comment: Cuando contesté a la pregunta había otro código, como dice en los comentarios debería poner más información acerca de la estructura en C que está utilizando para reemplazar a std:vector